# Don't close the browser till file download is complete

Tags: java, selenium

I've a below scenario in selenium with Java that needs to be automated.

On a webpage , after giving input values there is an export to Excel button. After clicking on the export button I need to wait  till the export is complete. My browser shouldn't be closed unless and until the export is completed.
Note: After export completes , there is no message that will be displayed so not sure how to handle it.

Please help with the logic for above.

Comment: In which location file is getting downloaded ? also do you know the name of file in advance ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes , I've the file name that will be downloaded. File usually gets downloaded in downloads folder of any user If I'm not wrong. or will it differ?

Comment: It may get downloaded in different folder, that's the configuration you must be having in your automation suite, can you confirm if it's get downloaded in download folder ?

Comment: Will it display any % while exporting? like 25%, 50%...

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes , I just verified. Its getting downloaded in downloads folder

Comment: @NandanA No , it won't

Comment: @Yamini :  try out the below solution, it may be helpful to you. Let me know if you run into any issue.

Comment: @Yamini please try the below solution

Comment: @Yamini does any one of the solution works for your question?

Comment: @NandanA I'm yet to try it. surely I'll update you guys once I try it. Thanks much for the solution

Comment: @cruisepandey Hi Cruise , I did try your solution.  It helped me with the problem but I'm missing one check here.. I'm assigning the returned value from the given function and passing it to a variable and if the variable is ==true , we don't  download the file and browser exists as expected. but when its false , I did below and the file is getting downloaded after which its not returning to the main func call , bcoz the variable is not setting to true , it remains false.

Comment: boolean check = CommonMethods.isFileDownloaded(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\exportedFiles", "My file name here");
      if(check == true){
       System.out.println("File available");
      }else{
       while(!check){
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       //break; 
       }

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. This issue is  resolved now. will be back with new issue :P :P @NandanA

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. This issue is  resolved now. will be back with new issue :P :P @cruisepandey

Comment: @Yamini : Sure you are welcome to create new tickets whenever it's required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the download location, and file path in advance you can use the below method,

```
  public boolean isFileDownloaded(String downloadPath, String fileName) {
  File dir = new File(downloadPath);
  File[] dirContents = dir.listFiles();

  for (int i = 0; i < dirContents.length; i++) {
      if (dirContents[i].getName().equals(fileName)) {
          // File has been found
          return true;
      }
          }
      return false;
  }
```

the above method should return a boolean based on file presence in your folder.

so you can have a logic like if this method return true, which means file is there so now you can close the browser session. if it returns false, then do not close the session and wait for sometime and then check again.

**Update :**

```
boolean check = CommonMethods.isFileDownloaded(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\exportedFiles", "My file name here"); 

while(true){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    check = CommonMethods.isFileDownloaded(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\exportedFiles", "My file name here"); 
    if(check) {
        System.out.println("File available");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Yamini : Check out the updated code above.

Comment: Just a question. If download is failed then won't it be in a continuous loop?

Comment: @NandanA you're right , need to handle that part. maybe I can log an exception or do a Assert.fail since I'm using TestNG.. Any suggestions here?

Comment: @Yamini : Sounds good, you can make assertion failure after certain amount of time

Answer (score 1):

Let's say file is taking around 30 seconds to get downloaded. Meanwhile, we need to keep checking the directory to make sure whether file is downloaded or not. So here we have to pass an time input for a check.

In below code, I have given `waitTillSeconds` value as `30 seconds` that means it will check the directory continuously up to 30 seconds. If the file is found at `15 seconds` then it returns the `boolean` value as `true` and skips the remaining `15 seconds`.

```
public boolean isFileAvailable(String downloadPath, String fileName) {

        int waitTillSeconds = 30;
        boolean fileDownloaded = false;

        long waitTillTime = Instant.now().getEpochSecond() + waitTillSeconds;

        while (Instant.now().getEpochSecond() < waitTillTime) {

            File dir = new File(downloadPath);
            File[] dirContents = dir.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < dirContents.length; i++) {
                if (dirContents[i].getName().equals(fileName)) {
                    System.out.println("File downloaded.");
                    fileDownloaded = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (fileDownloaded) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return fileDownloaded;
    }
```

**Why we need to give time input?**

Sometimes file may get downloaded immediately and sometimes it will take extra time to download based on the internet speed, application slowness or other factors so it is good to give the time for download.

Comment: @Yamini That's why I added a certain time input in my code.

Comment: Got you. Lemme try this and revert